# Load external page inside ng-view with AngularJs in an SPA application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, angular-routing

Is there a way of insert an external web page inside angularjs `ng-view`.
For example when I press a link with `ng-route` in my example I want that a external page load inside my own web page.

In this example, I wish that when I click external, another page should be loaded.
I have tried with ng-include and doesn't work.

http://plnkr.co/edit/vkAvZ2hGUjHlfHy0ul1z

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just use an iframe inside your partial template? (second.html)

http://plnkr.co/edit/DngozsvRhvJ3Ssr0amzK

Comment: I tried it but I was exploring another alternative. I frame give an error when I using WAMP but doesn't show errors in IIS